# Adding editable rows to a protected Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have a 100 row spreadsheet that others need to view, add rows and data within the 100 but cannot edit the original 100 rows.

I've protected the sheet and clicked the box to allow the addition of rows.  The problem is when others try to add data into the row they added, they are not allowed.

I saw a similar question where the answer was to add 2 rows between each row and hide one.  Not clear how that would help and seems a tedious task for a 100 row spreadsheet.

Is this possible?  I have limited (no) coding skills...
Thank you

Comment: This is a programming Q&A site for professional and enthusiastic programmers. *'Is it possible?'* is not a specific programming question and expressing your lack of programming knowledge only reinforces the fact that you've chosen to post a poor question  on the wrong site.

Comment: Why not allow rows to be added at the bottom, then if the new data is valid, do a sort to include the new rows in the appropriate place

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you want users to be able to edit, push <kbd>CTRl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and uncheck the Locked box from the Protection tab.

[image]

Note that non-programming questions are better suited to https://superuser.com/